# Weird Postfix Rejection

Tags: postfix

I am currently rebuilding a mailserver with postfix and am working on some reject rules.

```
postconf -d | grep mail_version
mail_version = 2.10.1
```

I am having problems with this section:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unauth_destination
```

It should be implemented in my version of postfix according to this document: http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html but for some reason when I have it implemented i always get this error:

```
postfix/smtpd[8865]: fatal: in parameter smtpd_relay_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions, specify at least one working instance of: reject_unauth_destination, defer_unauth_destination, reject, defer, defer_if_permit or check_relay_domains
```

Even though I have "reject_unauth_destination" included it fails to see it.

I am stuck for ideas around this.

Comment: You might have some sort of whitespace problem. Does it work if you place them all on one line?

Comment: Can you paste your entire config (perhaps stripped a bit for sensitive data). Maybe you have `smtpd_relay_restrictions` twice in the config?

Comment: @michael-hampton...damn it :) gold star goes to you...there was a hidden character on the second line. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @MichaelHampton, there was an invisible character on the line.